# Calling a view and its controller from _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my _Layout, I try to call a view and its controller. View is Menu.cshtml.

Problem is that View Menu doesn't recognize its parameters.

**_Layout (in folder /Shared/):**

```
<div id="menu" >

   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Menu/Menu.cshtml")                    

</div>
```

**Menu.cshtml (in folder /Views/):**

```
@model MenuModel
<ul id="menu">
    @{
        foreach (var iteparent in Model.ParentMenuModel) // Error: Model.ParentMenuController is not recognized
        {

        // do some stuff

        }                
     }
</ul>
```

**MenuController (in folder /Controllers/)**

```
    public class MenuController : Controller
        {

            public ActionResult Index()
            {            
                MenuModel objmenumodel = new MenuModel();

                objmenumodel.ParentMenuModel = new List<BE_MENU>();
                objmenumodel.ParentMenuModel = ParentMenuList();

                return PartialView(objmenumodel);
            }

          public List<BE_MENU> ParentMenuList()
          {
            List<BE_MENU> objparentmenu = new List<BE_MENU>();
            objparentmenu.Add(new BE_MENU { ID_MENU = 1, TXT_MENU = "Home", PARENT_ID = 0, URL = "#" });                
            return objparentmenu;

          }

        }
```

When View Menu is loaded, it gets error because parameter Model.ParentMenuModel is not recognized.

How is the correct way to call a view and its controller from _Layout?

I can do run it without error when View is in folder Shared, but would like to call an independent View and its Controller.

**EDIT :**

I tried to use  @Html.Action("Index","Menu"), but gets error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Html.Partial` helper method **will not** invoke your action method. Your partial view for menu is strongly typed to `MenuModel` class and inside the partial view you are accessing the `ParentMenuModel` property of your Model. You are getting the exception because the model passed into the view is `NULL`(*because you did not pass any*) and you are trying to access a property on a `NULL` object!

So either you should explicitly pass it(*an object of `MenuModel`*) when calling the `Html.Partial` method or your the main view ( which is calling this partial) should be also typed to the same model(`MenuModel`)

What you should be doing is, Instead of calling `Html.Partial`, you should use `Html.Action` method.

```
<div id="menu" >
     @Html.Action("Index","Menu")
</div>
```

This will execute the `Index` action method in `MenuController` which will pass an object of `MenuModel` to the partial view for menu.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it gets error. Is it possible to call a View, which is not in Shared folder, from _Layout ?

Comment: What error are you getting ? Yes. you can call a view from some other folder other than Shared folder. You just need to specify the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call and render the results of an existing Action, you need to use the [`Html.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721266(v=vs.118).aspx) HTML Helper method :

```
<div id="menu" >
   @Html.Action("Index","Menu")
</div>
```

The [`Html.Partial()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402898(v=vs.118).aspx) helper will just attempt to render the View directly without ever accessing the controller, so if you don't have a model being passed into it via `Html.Partial("{view-location}", YourViewModel)`, your model will always be `null` within the View.

Generally speaking, if you already have an instance of the Model you are using or your View doesn't require a model at all, `Html.Partial()` is probably okay. Otherwise, if you need to hit a Controller Action, `Html.Action()` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
<div id="menu" >

   @Html.Partial("MenuIndex") // I'm changing the name, because probably you must have other page or method with the same name                    

</div>
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult MenuIndex()
{
    MenuModel objmenumodel = new MenuModel();

    objmenumodel.ParentMenuModel = new List<BE_MENU>();
    objmenumodel.ParentMenuModel = ParentMenuList();

    return PartialView(objmenumodel);
}

    public List<BE_MENU> ParentMenuList()
    {
        List<BE_MENU> objparentmenu = new List<BE_MENU>();
       objparentmenu.Add(new BE_MENU { ID_MENU = 1, TXT_MENU = "Home", PARENT_ID = 0, URL = "#" });

        return objparentmenu;

    }
```